# Having trouble deploying my dockerized MERN-stack web app with nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, nginx, mern

Sorry if the title is a bit vague, but I'm honestly not sure how to summarize it better. So I spent the last few weeks writing a simple Todo app, nothing fancy, and I wanted to try my hands on the whole devops/deployment flow of things. So, I decided to dockerize my UI (React), API (Express/nodejs), and DB (Mongodb). Running everything locally, it seemed to run smoothly. Mind you, I was still building the development image of React, so I didn't need Nginx at this point to host the files.

Now fast forward to a week ago to when I decided to move it onto a Digital Ocean Droplet. First, I read up a little and realized building the UI as production and hosting the static files in an nginx container was a good idea. I figured I could also use the nginx container as a load balancer and route any and all requests to :8080 to either my UI or API, depending if the url started with /api or not. The axiosClient of my UI could then also have the base address of: :8080/api, so as to send the request to the droplet and have nginx route it to the API container. Maybe a bit of a detour, but I figured it'd let me ignore having to keep track of the API container ip-address, since it'd be set up automatically with my docker-compose.yml and used in my nginx.conf.

Setup looks something like this:
[image]

Now the problem is that I when send a POST request through my UI (I know it comes from my PC) I get a 405 not allowed, but in a really weird way: the baseURL seems to be duplicated like this
http://123.456.7.89:8080/123.456.7.89:8080/api/v1/auth/signup. I'm really at a loss, and I'm tired, so apologies if I need to supplement more information, I'll try to give them to you. But checking the logs of my backend container, nothing seems to arrive there. I feel like MERN + docker & nginx should be a pretty standard setup, but I think I'm missing something here.

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.456.7.89;

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    image: <react_image>
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - frontend-backend
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    hostname: backend
    image: <backend_image>
    expose:
      - ${ORG_BACKEND_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PORT=${ORG_BACKEND_PORT}
      - MONGODB_URL=mongodb://db:27017/organizer
      - SECRET_KEY=${ORG_SECRET_KEY}
      - TOKEN_KEY=${ORG_TOKEN_KEY}
    networks:
      - frontend-backend
      - backend-db
  db:
    container_name: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    networks:
      - backend-db

networks:
  backend-db:
  frontend-backend:
```

Given the configuration, I was expecting my request to be routed to my backend container by nginx, and I'd get a 200 status.

Comment: Have you tried setting `location /api {` to `location /api/ {`? (trailing slash)

Comment: If that doesn't work, try adding the trailing slash to the `proxy_pass` directive. I can't remember the specifics but I've had this kind of problem and it's usually just a case of "aligning" directories.

Comment: @jhmckimm you beautiful son of a bitch, I think that was it! Granted, I went back and forth doing a bunch of stuff, and now it seems to be working? But I think the big change I did was what you suggested. Thanks for taking the time to respond, you saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: Can I mark your answer as the solution and lock this thread somehow?

Comment: No, because these are just comments - but you are free to answer your own question. :)